# What would the relationship be in terms of an ERD?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, erd

I'm designing an online learning platform, in that I have entities like Instructor and Courses. Currently the relationship they are having is Many to Many, with a third table which joins the two entities. I wanted to know for sure if this is the most suitable solution or is there even some better way to associate the two?

Comment: I believe that's the best way to deal with many to many. The bridge table help us to avoid duplicates in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think a many to many relationship is just right for your use case. However, you should be careful how you implement the multiplicities.

So if the relationship is defined as (1...n) <--> (1..n) then every instructor you want to store must have at least one course.
If you want to store an instructor who has no courses yet, I would recommend the following: (0...n) <--> (1..n).